Facing error Invalid or corrupted pad block
I get an error when I attempt to decrypt the following in Flutter:
final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
final encryptedText = 'QfzgPWV2ugNzsntWfW1YLA==';

  try {
      final decrypter =
          encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc));
      final decrypted = decrypter.decrypt64(encryptedText, iv: iv);
      print(decrypted);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Decryption failed: $e");
    }


"I get an error" is not very useful for us. What's the error? show us any stacktraces if possible
